# Is OpenNLP unable to identify dates of the format "January 10th, 2009"?

Tags: java, date, text-mining, opennlp

OpenNLP(in Java) is unable to identify dates of the format "January 10th, 2010" or "January 10, 2010". I replaced all ','s in the text with an empty string "" before using OpenNLP tokenizer and it works fine for dates of the form "January 10, 2010". So, I tried to replace "th," with ",", but it did not work. How can we make sure that the dates of the above forms are identified with OpenNLP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after replacement in what format your date is? is it the same acceptible format

Comment: if you do the "`th`" replace first, the resulting output should be identical for the two inputs.  Hence if one format is working and the other isn't, your replaces aren't working as one would expect and you should see what the text is after all replacements have run.

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation of date finding and format, this [newer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419337/opennlp-name-entity-recognition-model-for-time-and-date) works well.  It talks about the models recognizing dates within the context of the tokens around it since it is a statistical model.

For the th case above, as the comment says if you want to replace both the th and the , then you have to apply both replaces, or better yet do a single replace of th, with empty string.