# OpenNLP Name entity recognition model for time and date

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I am using OpenNLP models for Name-entity recognition.

I am passing sentences, in which I want to identify words.
Open NLP requires a String [] variable, hence I split my String into words separated by space.

I am facing the problem to recognize the Date. If for example the string contains the date: 7 Jan 2012 and I split the string into words, "7", "Jan" and "2012" get separated as 3 different words. Although they are recognized as dates but the 3 different tokens don't make sense for me for further processing.
How can I possibly split my string, so that "2 Jan 2012" can be taken as one string...
7 Jan 2012 is one format... Sometimes it is also Jan 7,2012. Date also recognizes the time format I input: like 12:18pm

The NER time model is does not recognize the time in 12:18pm or 09:52:52 .. What kind of time format does it accept?

Answer (score 2):

Apache OpenNLP date and time model are statistical, trained from a corpus. It will recognize date and time from the context, not only from the format.

If you have specific needs you can create your own corpus and [train](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training) your own OpenNLP Name 
Finder model.

OpenNLP Name Finder also supports some customization while training. Maybe if you create a corpus, and also add some [regex based features](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.featuregen) you can improve your results.